# Select data from SQL DB per day

Tags: sql

I have a table with order information in an E-commerce store. Schema looks like this:

[Orders]
Id|SubTotal|TaxAmount|ShippingAmount|DateCreated

**This table does only contain data for every Order. So if a day goes by without any orders, no sales data is there for that day.**

I would like to select subtotal-per-day for the last 30 days, including those days with no sales.

The resultset would look like this:

Date       | SalesSum
2009-08-01 | 15235
2009-08-02 | 0
2009-08-03 | 340
2009-08-04 | 0
...

Doing this, only gives me data for those days with orders:

```
select DateCreated as Date, sum(ordersubtotal) as SalesSum
from Orders
group by DateCreated
```

You could create a table called Dates, and select from that table and join the Orders table. But I really want to avoid that, because it doesn't work good enough when dealing with different time zones and things...

Please don't laugh. SQL is not my kind of thing... :)

Comment: What are you using? Answers may vary if you're using MySQL, or SQL Server, or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that can generate a date table as follows:
(stolen from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenerateDateTable.aspx)

```
Create Function dbo.fnDateTable
(
  @StartDate datetime,
  @EndDate datetime,
  @DayPart char(5) -- support 'day','month','year','hour', default 'day'
)
Returns @Result Table
(
  [Date] datetime
)
As
Begin
  Declare @CurrentDate datetime
  Set @CurrentDate=@StartDate
  While @CurrentDate<=@EndDate
  Begin
    Insert Into @Result Values (@CurrentDate)
    Select @CurrentDate=
    Case
    When @DayPart='year' Then DateAdd(yy,1,@CurrentDate)
    When @DayPart='month' Then DateAdd(mm,1,@CurrentDate)
    When @DayPart='hour' Then DateAdd(hh,1,@CurrentDate)
    Else
      DateAdd(dd,1,@CurrentDate)
    End
  End
  Return
End
```

Then, join against that table

```
SELECT dates.Date as Date, sum(SubTotal+TaxAmount+ShippingAmount)
FROM [fnDateTable] (dateadd("m",-1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111),'day') dates 
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON dates.Date = DateCreated
GROUP BY dates.Date
```

Comment: With a slightly modified Select statment, it works:

SELECT dates.date, ISNULL(SUM(ordersubtotal), 0) as Sales FROM [dbo].[DateTable] ('2009-08-01','2009-08-31','day') datesLEFT JOIN Orders ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Orders.datecreated, 111) = dates.dategroup by dates.date

Comment: I updated the second query. I had the wrong date field in the select/group by, so that limited it to only dates with sales. I tested this version, and I think it gives what you want. It has NULLs instead of 0s for days without sales, but you could easily use the COALESCE function to wipe those out.

Comment: I can't get this to work for cheese. Can someone show me the exact correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @oldest_date datetime
declare @daily_sum numeric(18,2)
declare @temp table(
    sales_date datetime,
    sales_sum numeric(18,2)
)
select @oldest_date = dateadd(day,-30,getdate())

while @oldest_date <= getdate()
begin
    set @daily_sum = (select sum(SubTotal) from SalesTable  where DateCreated = @oldest_date)
    insert into @temp(sales_date, sales_sum) values(@oldest_date, @daily_sum)
    set @oldest_date = dateadd(day,1,@oldest_date)
end

select * from @temp
```

OK - I missed that 'last 30 days' part. The bit above, while not as clean, IMHO, as the date table, should work. Another variant would be to use the while loop to fill a temp table just with the last 30 days and do a left outer join with the result of my original query.

Comment: Just add a where clause for the last 30 days

Comment: This won't include any days that don't have any sales in them (as originally requested)

Comment: If was just that easy :) I need every day, for the last 30 days.

Comment: OK - This bit isn't well-tested, but it should work. If not, it's not far off.

Answer (score 1):

> including those days with no sales.

That's the difficult part.  I don't think the first answer will help you with that.  I did something similar to this with a separate date table.

You can find the directions on how to do so here:

[Date Table](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Comment: Actually, I was under the assumption that days without sales would not be in the table.  If not, disregard my answer.

Comment: It isn't. The table only contains data per Order. So if a day goes by with no orders, no sales data is there for that particular day.

Comment: Then I would create a date table with all dates and then do a left join to a query which would summarize the sales per day.  You would also remember to use a coalesce statement to return zero instead of null for days without sales.   I've had to do this in many different situations and the external date table was the way to go.

Comment: I've seen times when this Dates table have wrong dates, week numbers and things. I really want to avoid this.

Comment: Well, if you don't use a table which has all of the dates for your time period, then you will skip dates where there are no sales. 

You would get:

2009-08-01 | 15235
2009-08-03 | 340

The script is well documented and easy to understand, but written for T-SQL.  I still think this is the way to go.

Comment: It has some issued regarding week numbers, and different time zones, daylight saving times etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Log table table with LogID an index which i never delete any records. it has index from 1 to ~10000000. Using this table I can write

```
select 
     s.ddate, SUM(isnull(o.SubTotal,0))
from 
    (
        select 
            cast(datediff(d,LogID,getdate()) as datetime) AS ddate 
        from
            Log 
        where 
            LogID <31
    ) s right join orders o on o.orderdate = s.ddate
group by s.ddate
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this today. We also got a e-commerce application. I don't want to fill our database with "useless" dates. I just do the group by and create all the days for the last N days in Java, and peer them with the date/sales results from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this ultimately going to end up? I ask only because it may be easier to fill in the empty days with whatever program is going to deal with the data instead of trying to get it done in SQL.

SQL is a wonderful language, and it is capable of a great many things, but sometimes you're just better off working the finer points of the data in the program instead.

Answer (score 0):

(Revised a bit--I hit enter too soon)

I started poking at this, and as it hits some pretty tricky SQL concepts it quickly grew into the following monster. If feasible, you might be better off adapting THEn's solution; or, like many others advise, using application code to fill in the gaps could be preferrable.

```
--  A temp table holding the 30 dates that you want to check
DECLARE @Foo Table (Date  smalldatetime  not null)

--  Populate the table using a common "tally table" methodology (I got this from SQL Server magazine long ago)
;WITH
  L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1), --2 rows
  L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),--4 rows
  L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),--16 rows
  L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),--256 rows
  Tally AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C) AS Number FROM L3)
INSERT @Foo (Date)
 select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, dateadd(dd, -number + 1, getdate())), 0)
 from Tally
 where Number < 31
```

Step 1 is to build a temp table containint the 30 dates that you are concerned with. That abstract wierdness is about the fastest way known to build a table of consecutive integers; add a few more subqueries, and you can populate millions or more in mere seconds. I take the first 30, and use dateadd and the current date/time to convert them into dates.  If you already have a "fixed" table that has 1-30, you can use that and skip the CTE entirely (by replacing table "Tally" with your table).

The outer two date function calls remove the time portion of the generated string.

(Note that I assume that your order date also has no time portion -- otherwise you've got another common problem to resolve.)

For testing purposes I built table #Orders, and this gets you the rest:

```
SELECT f.Date, sum(ordersubtotal) as SalesSum
 from @Foo f
  left outer join #Orders o
   on o.DateCreated = f.Date
 group by f.Date
```

Comment: This is based on SQL Server 2005, wherein common table expressions (that ugly "WITH" clause) were introduced. There are other ways to get these results, but the CTE is quickest for ad hoc tally table builds.

Answer (score 0):

I created the Function DateTable as JamesMLV pointed out to me.

And then the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT dates.date, ISNULL(SUM(ordersubtotal), 0) as Sales FROM [dbo].[DateTable] ('2009-08-01','2009-08-31','day') dates
LEFT JOIN Orders ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Orders.datecreated, 111) = dates.date
group by dates.date
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DateCreated,
SUM(SubTotal) AS SalesSum
FROM Orders
GROUP BY DateCreated
```